# Cancel a Call for User Input C++

Tags: c++, timer, user-input

How would I effectively cancel a call for user input if there is no input within a certain time? (I'm programming a game for a terminal/cmd window with Mac OS X).

I have tried turning off canonical buffering and using a timer thread that joins after the call for user input. I also tried implementing the call to `pthread_join()` within the parameters of the while loop. Still nothing. The problem is that even though canonical buffering is off, the call for user input is still held up when there is no input. It works fine if there is input though.

It would be great if I could do this without fiddling around with downloading and installing ncurses, but I'll do it if I have to.

Edit: Source code:

```
//Most headers only pertain to my main program. 
#include <iostream>
#include <termios.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

//Timer function.
void *Timer(void*) {

    time_t time1, time2;

    time1 = time(NULL);

    while (time2 - time1 < 1) {
        time2 = time(NULL);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {

    //Remove canonical buffering.
    struct termios t_old, t_new;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &t_old);
    t_new = t_old;
    t_new.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &t_new);

    cout << "Press any key to continue." << endl;

    string szInput;

    int control = 0;

    do {

        pthread_t inputTimer;

        pthread_create(&inputTimer, NULL, Timer, NULL);

        szInput = "";

        while (szInput == "") {

            szInput = cin.get();


            //Handle keypresses instantly.
            if (szInput == "a") {
                cout << endl << "Instant keypress." << endl;
            }
        }    

        pthread_join(inputTimer, NULL); 

        cout << endl << "One second interval." << endl;

        control ++;

    } while (control < 25);

    cout << "Game Over." << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: How are you reading the input from the user? With streams (e.g. `cin`), stdio (e.g. `scanf`/`fgets`/`fgetc`) or system calls (e.g. `read`)? It would help if you could show some (minimal and relevant) code.

Comment: While still don't know what method of input you are using, you should really turn off all buffering. Either that or use some polling technique like using `select` to see if it's possible to read from `STDIN_FILENO`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Thanks to your second suggestion, I was able to solve my problem. If you make an official answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of checking if there is input is to poll the file descriptor `STDIN_FILENO` using e.g. the `select` system call. If `STDIN_FILENO` is readable, then you can read at at least one character. You can also pass a timeout to the `select` call.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works!

```
char ch;  //Input character
int time = 0;     //Time iterator
int TIMER = 5000; //5 seconds
while(time<TIMER)
{
    if(!kbhit())
    {
        time = 0;
        ch = getch();
        //Do your processing on keypress
    }
    time++;
    delay(1);
}
```

`kbhit()` detects if any keystroke has occurred. If yes, then get the key character in `ch`.

Comment: Because I currently have no access to my Windows computer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Shashwat, it works with the below modifications:

1) Changing `if(!kbhit())` to `if(kbhit())`

2) Changing `delay(1);` to `Sleep(1);`

I do not have enough rep to post a comment, hence adding as an answer.